# Get parent of child in Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am having a problem retrieving the child key and parent key from a Firebase database.

I have a firebase database that looks like this:

```
- friendlies
    - 38UUDYtde4WF5AVcxcw6o9qaPBM2
        - GYtQbt3KX1RveVeBAHd08u0Pdm42: true
    - GYtQbt3KX1RveVeBAHd08u0Pdm42
        - 38UUDYtde4WF5AVcxcw6o9qaPBM2: true
```

I am successfully getting this data via:

```
var REF_FRIENDLIES = Database.database().reference().child("friendlies")
REF.FRIENDLIES.queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {
        snapshot in
        snapshot.children.forEach({
            (snapChild) in
            print("SnapChild: \(snapChild)")
            let child = snapChild as! DataSnapshot
            print("Child Key: \(child.key)")
            print("Child Parent Key: \(child.ref.parent?.key)")
        })
        print("Snapshot: \(snapshot)")
    })
```

Which has the following output:

```
SnapChild: Snap (38UUDYtde4WF5AVcxcw6o9qaPBM2) {
    GYtQbt3KX1RveVeBAHd08u0Pdm42 = 1;
}
Child Key: 38UUDYtde4WF5AVcxcw6o9qaPBM2
Child Parent Key: Optional("friendlies")


SnapChild: Snap (GYtQbt3KX1RveVeBAHd08u0Pdm42) {
    38UUDYtde4WF5AVcxcw6o9qaPBM2 = 1;
}
Child Key: GYtQbt3KX1RveVeBAHd08u0Pdm42
Child Parent Key: Optional("friendlies")


Snapshot: Snap (friendlies) {
    38UUDYtde4WF5AVcxcw6o9qaPBM2 =     {
        GYtQbt3KX1RveVeBAHd08u0Pdm42 = 1;
    };
    GYtQbt3KX1RveVeBAHd08u0Pdm42 =     {
        38UUDYtde4WF5AVcxcw6o9qaPBM2 = 1;
    };
}
```

The child key is working properly; the problem I'm having is retrieving the parent data. What I want to return is a child ID, as well as its holder/parent data. So, I want to return `GYtQbt3KX1RveVeBAHd08u0Pdm42` as the child key, but retrieve `38UUDYtde4WF5AVcxcw6o9qaPBM2` as the parent key, but what returns instead as the parent is `friendlies`.

The snapshot clearly contains this, but I am at a loss at how to access it.

**EDIT**:

So `child.ref.description()` will return me the node I want, but at the end of my database's address:

`https://my-project.firebaseio.com/friendlies/38UUDYtde4WF5AVcxcw6o9qaPBM2` and I can just replace the url part of the String, but this seems like a really bad practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're looping over `snapshot.children`, the key of the parent is always going to be `snapshot.key`.

---

What I think you're trying to do is traverse the two level of child nodes under `friendlies`. But for that you will need *two* loops:

```
var REF_FRIENDLIES = Database.database().reference().child("friendlies")
REF.FRIENDLIES.queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {
        snapshot in
        snapshot.children.forEach({ (snapChild) in
            let child = snapChild as! DataSnapshot
            child.children.forEach({ (snapGrandchild) in
                let grandchild = snapGrandchild as! DataSnapshot
                print("Grandchild Key: \(grandchild.key)")
                print("Grandchild Parent Key: \(child.key)")
            })
        })
    })
```

I might be missing some null handling in the code, but I hope the flow is clear.

Comment: Thanks for having a look, I'll try it out right now

Comment: That did it, thanks a lot, saved me a lot of time for sure.

Comment: Just came back to this after a break and it's all something too clear. Good Grief.